# The OAuth client was deleted

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-apps-script-addon

I'm in the process of publishing a Google Sheets Add-on. I possibly deleted the OAuth Client Id and recreated it. Now, the add-on gets installed. It hasn't been verified by Google yet, so asks the user to grant permission. At this point I get the following error:

```
401. That’s an error.

Error: deleted_client

The OAuth client was deleted.

Request Details
That’s all we know.

The details when 'Request Details' is clicked provides the following information.

client_id=********
redirect_uri=https://script.google.com/oauthcallback
state=ACjPJvFGKcWpzCmlAtvQGzrYb-PfmmsvXbwM_dfV7tDDyS-aF6sekF6WH4IopzGCTJY1CpNOLFrHkMv74tbKGDoXayTEu_v8sS18dsIDJ4uXEOQ0EwfRrx9dO4ApMR9yZbGWGXqeXW79hpqRm4FoG7nMZlcRiDe0ZOOu25-eiOw_kD49HGw3x6qmQlM9g0xf9PKMKFVNPq58FjjCpnC_sLyrmMA3jTMNL0W8F1nxuzFNM66-RvhKypOYwOKN7ztDs6ZBkoRERB54nrnp0qPEpJl1FyAT6-SxA9GagCHYnwB7i5jHlqCDjpB2LtxjzziFO9TlEsmd6pi3DVkNOkJRDrWHWEmUh685mNL0p-CdQCfSzHzZLY51Va_gDqHdKg43TP9Hadt8hh7uIMdBTpPQbkWqTj5WFstN0e4GIyTtfM94xSl6CHDvsD3PJ7Mdljad2qQ4W9GWhQ
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
response_type=none gsession
access_type=offline
approval_prompt=force
hl=en
login_hint=*******
```

I'm new to the Google Cloud platform and chrome web store and G-Suite marketplace publishing. I have tried searching StackOverflow and the internet for this error, with no luck. I have currently only published via the web store and am getting this error. 
I probably need to update the client id as it doesn't match the one that I have in the project right now. I don't know where to find and edit it

I have seen several similar questions but nothing relevant to an editor addon or answered. Please help as there aren't any resources to learn about this

Comment: If you deleted the client id and created a new one, are you using the new client id and secret?

Comment: How do I do that? The process I followed as per the official documentation, didn't tell me anything about it

Answer (score 0):

I created and used a new cloud platform project and went through the whole process again, that did the trick